# How do I list all tables in a schema having specific column in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have found the list of all tables using this query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM USER_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

But I need to list all the tables having column name `starttime_date` or `starttime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `USER_TAB_COLS` view.

For example,

```
SQL> select table_name, column_name, data_type from user_tab_cols where column_name ='DEPTNO';

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM DATA_TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
DEPT       DEPTNO     NUMBER
EMP        DEPTNO     NUMBER

SQL>
```

You could try,

```
select * 
   from user_tab_cols
 where column_name in ('STARTTIME_DATE', 'STARTTIME');
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you connect any schema then you could try to this SQL.

For example:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       DATA_TYPE,
       DATA_LENGTH,
       NULLABLE
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE OWNER = 'schema_name' and column_name = 'column_name';
```

[image]